# How can I change the source source of an image by clicking on another picture?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm basically making a Rock paper scissor game. I want to change the hand based on what the user clicks on. So if the user click on the rock image then a rock hand will show. Basically like this:

[image]
[image]

I made a function using "if" statements but it's not working, I'm stuck. The HTML and JavaScript are below. Can someone please help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be better to post those codes as plain text in the question!

Comment: Images of code suck.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to pass a string as a parameter on each of your images like: `onclick="RkPSc('rock')"` which will tell the function which image to change to.

```
<img src="rock.jpg" onclick="RkPSc('rock')" />
<img src="paper.jpg" onclick="RkPSc('paper')" />
<img src="scissors.jpg" onclick="RkPSc('scissors')" />
```

Then, in your javascript, modify the function to accept a parameter and change your image based on that parameter.

```
function RkPSc(item) {
    var lefthand = document.getElementById('lefthand');

    if(item === 'rock')
        lefthand.src = 'leftRockHand.jpg';
    else if(item === 'scissors')
        lefthand.src = 'leftScissorHand.jpg';
    else
        lefthand.src = 'leftPaperHand.jpg';
}
```